# Atmos - Cyberduck

Tags: object-storage, swisscomdev, cyberduck

If you like to use the S3 with the popular Cyberduck app, from Swisscom Application Cloud you have to use a custom connection profile with AWS2.
You can find this profile [here](https://trac.cyberduck.io/wiki/help/en/howto/s3#AuthenticationwithsignatureversionAWS2) for download

> Authentication with signature version AWS2 
>   Incomplete list of known providers that require the use of AWS2 
>   Riak Cloud Storage 
>   EMC Elastic Cloud Storage

Answer (score 5):

Thank you very much for sharing this nice tool tip. I added here a few screenshots for clarification.

1) `brew cask install cyberduck`

2) Download linked `S3 AWS2 Signature Version (HTTPS).cyberduckprofile` File and open it with Cyberduck.

3) copy credentials and host from `cf env` or create service keys.

```
System-Provided:
{
 "VCAP_SERVICES": {
  "dynstrg": [
   {
    "credentials": {
     "accessHost": "ds31s3.swisscom.com",
     "accessKey": "24324234234243456546/CF_P8_FFGTUZ_TGGLJS_JFG_B347EEACE",
     "sharedSecret": "sfdklaslkfklsdfklmsklmdfklsd"
    },
    "label": "dynstrg",
    "name": "cyberduck-testing",
    "plan": "usage",
    "provider": null,
    "syslog_drain_url": null,
    "tags": [],
    "volume_mounts": []
   }
  ],
```

sharedSecret is named "Secret Access Key" in Cyberduck

[image]

create initial bucket (it's called Folder in Cyberdurck)

[image]

upload with Drag and Drop some files

[image]

Some commandline alternatives (Open Source) what some people use with Swisscom's EMC Atmos (dynstrg Service) are

- [S3cmd](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd)

> S3cmd is a free command line tool and client for uploading, retrieving
>   and managing data in Amazon S3 and other cloud storage service
>   providers that use the S3 protocol, such as Google Cloud Storage or
>   DreamHost DreamObjects. It is best suited for power users who are
>   familiar with command line programs. It is also ideal for batch
>   scripts and automated backup to S3, triggered from cron, etc.

- [Minio Client](https://github.com/minio/mc)

> Minio Client is a replacement for ls, cp, mkdir, diff and rsync
>   commands for filesystems and object storage.